# Prove that $a_n$ has a convergent subsequence

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, convergence-divergence

Let $(a_nb_n)$ be a convergent sequence and $1 ≤ b_n ≤ 2$ for all $n$. Prove that $(a_n)$ has a convergent subsequence .

I am new to the real analysis and it would be appreciated if you could give me a hint on how to start to solve this question

Answer (score 4):

**Hint:** (given the question, I assume the sequences are real-valued)

$(a_n b_n)_n$ converges, so is bounded (can you see why?). Let $m, M\geq 0$ be such that $m \leq \lvert a_n b_n \rvert \leq M$ for all $n\in\mathbb{N}$. Then, since $b_n\neq 0$ for all $n$ we can write
$$
\lvert a_n\rvert =\frac{\lvert a_n b_n\rvert}{\lvert b_n\rvert} \leq \frac{M}{\lvert b_n\rvert} \leq \frac{M}{1} = M
$$
so $\lvert a_n\rvert\in\left[0,M\right]$ for all $n\in\mathbb{N}$: $(a_n)_n$ is a bounded sequence in $\mathbb{R}$. [Can you conclude](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bolzano%E2%80%93Weierstrass_theorem)?

**Edit:** no need for an upper bound on $\lvert b_n\rvert$, as Jonas Meyer pointed out below. A lower bound is sufficient.

Comment: It might be better to work with absolute values.  As stated, we could have $M<0$, in which case $M/b_n \le M/1$ doesn't follow from $b_n\ge 1$.  That could be dealt with by replacing $M$ with $\max(M,0)$, but we could also have $m<0$, which can't be dealt with the same way.  Arguing instead from $|a_nb_n|\le M$ avoids these issues.

Comment: Indeed -- will fix this. This now also has the advantage of working for sequences in $\mathbb{R}^d$, provided $1 \leq \lVert b_n\rVert \leq 2$.

Comment: I agree, but does it really matter?

Comment: I guess one advantage of omitting the lower bound for $|a_n|$ is that it makes it more clear that we didn't actually need the hypothesis that $b_n\le 2$.

Answer (score 1):

The sequence $b_n $ is bounded hence it has a convergence subsequence $b_{ n_m} $ its limit is $ \neq 0$. As $a_{ n_m}b_{n_m} $ is a subsequence of a convergence sequence it is convergente. Then $a_{n_m}=\dfrac{a_{ n_m}b_{n_m}}{b_{n_m}} $ is convergente.